# I am not able to scroll my layout in multi-window in Nougat 7.0

Tags: android, xml, layout, uiscrollview, android-7.0-nougat

To support multi-window in nougat 7.0 do i have to design all my layout with parent scrollview or is there any other way to make it work. Do i have to change all my old design to scrollview with min width & height to support multi-window. In android developer tutorial i got this code in this there is no scrolling concept and i am not able to scroll if i don't use scrollview.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
<layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
      android:defaultWidth="600dp"
      android:gravity="top|end"
      android:minHeight="450dp"
      android:minWidth="300dp" />
</activity>
```

Comment: "do i have to design all my layout with parent scrollview" -- no. "is there any other way to make it work" -- have a UI that fits small screens. That *may* involve scrolling, but there are lots of things in Android that scroll (`ListView`, `GridView`, `RecyclerView`, `WebView`, `MapView`, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare excluding all this listview, gridview etc which are default scroll. what about other normal layouts where scrolling functionality is not needed. like (Login page, Tabs, etc)

Comment: Either it fits or it does not fit. If you have been able to support `small` screen devices, your UI probably fits without adjustment. If it does not fit, you need to decide what to do: introduce scrolling, change the UI in general, change the UI specifically for small screens, etc.

Comment: i don't think it will fit if i support small screen devices maximum i can support is 3.7 which is there in layout.xml. if the screen size is 4" then its gonna be very difficult for user to use.

Comment: Then you need to introduce scrolling, change the UI in general, change the UI specifically for small screens, etc.